# Microeconomics Nash Equilibrium

Tags: game-theory, nash-equilibrium

Describe the process that you used to find the equilibria. Use this game to explain why it is important to describe an equilibrium by using the strategies employed by the players, not merely by the payoffs received in equilibrium.
                          ROWENA
                  Left      Centre     Right
           Up     (1,2)     (2,1)      (1,0)
COLLIN     Middle (0,5)     (1,2)      (7,4)
           Down   (-1,0)    (3,0)      (5,2)

Given this information, Kindly assist to answer the underlying question.

Comment: What have you tried so far?

Answer (score 0):

The first step would be to iteratively remove dominated strategies. Here, this process will end with a single cell: $(1,2)$. Note that this payoff vector appears twice in the matrix, but only one corresponds to a NE (which one?).